# Existence of a sequence with a given sum

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series

Let $(a_n)_{n=1}^\infty$ be a sequence of real numbers.
Let $(S_n)_{n=1}^\infty$ be the sequence of partial sums of $(a_n)_{n=1}^\infty$.

Prove or disprove:
There exists a sequence such that $S_n=1-\frac{1}{n^2}, \forall n\in N$.

I was immediately thinking about the telescoping series but I couldn't make it work.
I also tried to form other general sequences but that didn't work either.
So I assume that such sequence can't be formed, but I was unable to formalize a proof.
Can you please give me a hint?

Comment: $a_1=0, a_n=S_n-S_{n-1}$.

Comment: @KaviRamaMurthy Wow, I wasn't even close. Can you please try to explain how you thought about this?

Comment: $S_n$ is defined in terms of $a_n$'s and you can easily  write $a_n$ in terms of $S_n$'s by taking differences. Nothing special about $1-\frac 1 {n^{2}}$.

Comment: @KaviRamaMurthy Thank you

Comment: @KaviRamaMurthy How is that helps? Everything equals to zero here...

Answer (score 0):

As the intuition for finding an example was already covered in the comments, I will cut to the chase:

The statement is True. We define $\left(a_{n}\right)_{n=1}^{\infty}$ the following way:
$$a_{n}=\begin{cases}
0 & n=1\\
\frac{2n-1}{\left[n\left(n-1\right)\right]^{2}} & n>1,\;\;n\in \mathbb N
\end{cases}$$

While the case is clear for $N=1$, for every $N>1$ we have:
$$S_{N}=0+\sum_{n=2}^{N}\frac{2n-1}{n^{2}\left(n-1\right)^{2}}=0+\sum_{n=2}^{N}\left[\frac{1}{\left(n-1\right)^{2}}-\frac{1}{n^{2}}\right]=$$

$$\sum_{n=2}^{N}\frac{1}{\left(n-1\right)^{2}}-\sum_{n=2}^{N}\frac{1}{n^{2}}=\sum_{n=1}^{N-1}\frac{1}{n^{2}}-\sum_{n=2}^{N}\frac{1}{n^{2}}=1-\frac{1}{N^{2}}$$

thus $S_{N}=1-\frac{1}{N^{2}},\;\;\forall N\in \mathbb N$